# Actionscript3/flash cs4: how to resolve lag when launched from browser

Tags: flash, graphics, frame-rate, lag

I've been working for a month on a flash game, which should be manageable to play in a browser (light computation).  This being said, I've noticed that in some browsers the game runs at what looks like 15 fps (the game should run in 80fps).  This has been known to happen in IE9, and the quick fix was to add this line to the top of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">
```

This was a quick-fix that forces IE into compatibility mode and greatly improved the fps (to about... 60, let's say).

Still, I believe that the game is running slower than it should in every browser, which is evident when the html version is compared to the swf.

It's also fairly noticeable that the movement in the game (html) "lurches": these lurches injure the aesthetics of the game, and therefore the playability!

All of this leads me to believe that browsers limit access to computers' graphics card;

1) It's slow in html, and fast in swf

2) Sounds play at normal speed, yet graphics lag

**EDIT**

3) All the graphics in the game are fairly low resolution (i.e., graphics that are displayed ingame as width1xheight1 are movieclips of width1xheight1 png's) + as minimal as possible

4) I've made very (computationally) simple flash projects and seen the same graphic-movement problems.

Can anyone give me some advice as to how I can increase the smoothness of my game in browsers?

Comment: I believe that super high frame rates (above 50 fps) can actually slow the player in some browsers.  Try lowering it below 50.

Also, compressed graphics may be causing the stutter, due to the need to decompress them.  You also may want to look at object pooling, if you're not already, because the garbage collector can cause these stutters as it makes its rounds if you've released a lot of objects from memory.

Comment: In regards to "...high frame rates (above 50 fps)..." I have, just now, tried slowing the game down to < 50 fps and just coverted all increments in the game to match the movement in the 80fps version. No noticable difference :(.  Onto the second part about the graphics: I miss-spoke!! Using compressed graphics would be a bad idea!!!! I meant to say: the png's that are used in my graphic objects are the same resolution as they would appear in-game.
Now onto the garbage collector (G.C.):  I'm skeptical of this being the problem.  Shouldn't the G.C. work the same for both swf and html versions?

Comment: http://www.kaourantin.net/2006/05/frame-rates-in-flash-player.html

Comment: @Amy Nice! If that first comment was an answer I would +1 it.

Comment: @Casey Are these comparative swf and html versions both the release build? Have you added any other special code in the HTML? Perhaps you could show us the html code.

Comment: I'm not too adept at HTML, so I just used the generic "publish" command in flash.  So it looks like....

Comment: I found out recently that you can +1 comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a symptom of how the SWF is embedded in the HTML page. Flash supports a number of "window modes" which determine how the content is rendered into the browser window. This is set via the `wmode` parameter when the SWF is embedded in the HTML page.

According to [Adobe's documentation](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html), this should be set to "direct" for best performance:

> direct - Use direct to path rendering. This bypasses compositing in
>   the screen buffer and renders the SWF content directly to the screen.
>   This wmode value is recommended to provide the best performance for
>   content playback and enables hardware accelerated presentation of SWF
>   content that uses Stage Video or Stage 3D.

In practice, the `wmode` can act erratically so it may help to try the alternatives mentioned in the [documentation](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).

Other options which may help improve performance are:

- Use `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`. This will prevent content from being scaled should the embedded size not match the original size. Scaling contributes to CPU usage so disabling it should increase the frame-rate (see [StageScaleMode#NO_SCALE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html#NO_SCALE)).
- Set `opaqueBackground` on non-transparent MovieClips (such as the root MovieClip).  Transparency requires extra calculations to multiply the foreground color with the background color. Setting an opaque background bypasses these additional calculations and may result in a performance boost. (see [DisplayObject#opaqueBackground](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#opaqueBackground))